# Can someone help me with a card flip animation in Quasar Vue.js3?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, animation, quasar-framework

So i want to add a card flip effect on some cards, that should turn in a 3D animation when clicked around the y-axis for 180 degrees. On one side should be a question mark picture to cover the content of the backside of the card and when you click it it should turn around and reveal the backside. So far everything besides the animation and change of the card face works. When i click the card it mirrors itself on the y-axis but it doesn´t turn like a card nor shows the back of the card. If someone with a little more experience in quasar/vue could give me a hint or some explanation on how i get the desired effect done i would be really happy. So here is the code:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="page bg-brown-2 flex flex-center">
    <div class="canvas flex flex-center flex-wrap">
      <div v-for="(i,index) in numbers" :key="index" class="container">
        <div @click="e => e.target.classList.toggle('flip')" class="card">
          <div class="front">
            <q-img :src="require('../assets/question_mark.png')"/>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <q-img :src="require('../assets/pictures/' + i + '.png')"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>
<script>

export default ({
  name: 'BigPicturePage',

  data() {
    return {

<!-- This is hardcoded now but will be generated through a loop that fills the array at the start. pls don´t hate ^^´ -->
      numbers: [359,358,357,356,355,354,353,352,351,350,349,348,347,346,345,344,343,342,341,340,339,338,337,336,335,334,333,332,331,330,329,328,327,326,325,324,323,322,321,320,319,318,317,316,315,314,313,312,311,310,309,308,307,306,305,304,303,302,301,300,299,298,297,296,295,294,293,292,291,290,289,288,287,286,285,284,283,282,281,280,279,278,277,276,275,274,273,272,271,270,269,268,267,266,265,264,263,262,261,260,259,258,257,256,255,254,253,252,251,250,249,248,247,246,245,244,243,242,241,240,239,238,237,236,235,234,233,232,231,230,229,228,227,226,225,224,223,222,221,220,219,218,217,216,215,214,213,212,211,210,209,208,207,206,205,204,203,202,201,200,199,198,197,196,195,194,193,192,191,190,189,188,187,186,185,184,183,182,181,180,179,178,177,176,175,174,173,172,171,170,169,168,167,166,165,164,163,162,161,160,159,158,157,156,155,154,153,152,151,150,149,148,147,146,145,144,143,142,141,140,139,138,137,136,135,134,133,132,131,130,129,128,127,126,125,124,123,122,121,120,119,118,117,116,115,114,113,112,111,110,109,108,107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91,90,89,88,87,86,85,84,83,82,81,80,79,78,77,76,75,74,73,72,71,70,69,68,67,66,65,64,63,62,61,60,59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
    }
  },

  methods: {
},

  }
)

</script>

<style>

.canvas {
  height: 77.5vh;
  width: 70%;
}

.container {
  width: calc(100%/24);
  height: calc(100%/15);
  perspective: 500px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1500ms;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

</style>
```

I guess this animation has to be done in some Vue/Quasar way with some imported classes or attributes to do some fancy animations, but i am not experienced enough to get the right ressources for the exact structure.

Comment: Landed here while searching for similar issues. What I ended up doing was wrapping the `.front` and `.back` divs in a `transition-group` tag from vue. Add these attributes to transition: `appear enter-to-class="animated flipInX" leave-from-class="animated flipOutX"`, and enable `flipOutX` and `flipInX` animations in `quasar.config.js`. Sources: https://quasar.dev/options/animations, https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#css-based-transitions, https://animate.style/